# Replace text for every nth instance in a line

Tags: bash, loops, sed

I wish to replace every 6th instance of a space with a character "+" in a given line :

> Now is the Time for All Good Men to Come to the Aid of their Country. How much wood could a wood chuck chuck?

Attempting:
`sed "s/ /+/6;P;D" text.txt`

Which yields:

> Now is the Time for All+Good Men to Come to the Aid of their Country. How much wood could a wood chuck chuck?

I desire:

> Now is the Time for All+Good Men to Come to the+Aid of their Country. How much+wood could a wood chuck chuck?

I can deal with insert if replace won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with a `while` loop:

```sh
LINE="Now is the Time for All Good Men to Come to the Aid of their Country. How much wood could a wood chuck chuck?"

MAX=$(echo $LINE | grep -o " " | wc -l) # this counts number of spaces in $LINE

COUNTER=6
while [ $COUNTER -lt $MAX ]; do 
  LINE=$(echo $LINE | sed "s/ /+/${COUNTER};P;D")
  COUNTER=$(echo $(($COUNTER + 5)) )
done

echo $LINE
#Now is the Time for All+Good Men to Come to the+Aid of their Country. How much+wood could a wood chuck chuck?
```

In the `while` loop, I use `$COUNTER + 5` (not + 6) because we have to consider the space that has already changed to a "+" from the previous iteration (thus it is substituting the space at every 6-minus-1 instance).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

Insert `\n` after `+` and append to your command `| tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: That is likely the best way to go. I can't come up with any improvement on it.

Comment: I just found that out with one GNU sed: `sed -E 's/([^ ]+ ){6}/&+/g; s/ \+/+/g' file`

Comment: Now that one is even better, Think words followed by whtespace and then trim the additional whitespace. That's worth a 2nd but I only have 1.

Comment: with single substitution: `sed -E 's/([^ ]*( [^ ]+){5}) /\1+/g'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;ta;s/ /+\n/6;H;tb;z;x;s/\n//gp;d;:b;x;s/(.*)\n.*/\1/;x;D' file
```

This solution replaces every 6th space by `+\n` and appends the result to the hold space.

When the first substitution fails, the hold space is recalled and printed after first removing any newline artefacts introduced.

N.B. This solution strictly observes the OP specification "*replace every 6th instance of a space with a character "+" in a given line*" but may easily altered to obey a set of spaces rather than one,using:

```
sed -E ':a;ta;s/ +/+\n/6;H;tb;z;x;s/\n//gp;d;:b;x;s/(.*)\n.*/\1/;x;D' file
```

Also note the idiom `:a;ta` which resets the substitution internal success switch, which is necessary since the `D` command may leave the switch on.